# Can python source code executed using PyRun_SimpleString be extracted?

Tags: python, security, embed

I am developing a software based on embedded Python and C++. I want to secure some of my python code and prevent people from copying it.

For now I am using PyRun_SimpleString to execute the python code and the string is generated using my C++ code.

If I use this method, will it secure the Python code from being copied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I understand it the actual program will not exist in the executable, either in python source form, nor in 'marshalled' form (basically .pyc image) or compiled form, though I guess it will exist in some encrypted or obfuscated form which is converted into python source at run time.

This definitely makes it harder to extract the code, but an attacker who can trace the code as it runs will be able to catch calls to PyRun_SimpleString and obtain the plain source.

It's a question of degree - how hard you want to work to make the job harder for the attacker.

You might want to look into the 'frozen module' facility which is in the python source. This basically allows '.pyc' images to compiled in as byte arrays, and imported at runtime by un-marshalling them. So there's never any plain text source, but there is the .pyc image which is reasonably easy to analyze if you find it in the image. Take it one step further and obfuscate the pyc image - now attacker needs to analyze or trace past the de-obfuscation, and still won't see plain source code.

Comment: So,you mean that, in any case if a hacker catches the call to PyRun_SimpleString, he will be able to dump the entire python code?

In that case, I think only compiling into byte code is the possible means.

Comment: I am now trying to search for "Frozen Module" in Python. Still need to find a good example. Will post it once I manage to get it done.